# RE: Getting the name of the object onFocus & Adding Caption to a Button dynamically Created

Tags: vba, excel

I have written VBA code for Dynamically creating textboxes and buttons. The following is the code when I hit an "Add" button on the userform.

```
    Dim oTxtBox As Control
Dim oBrwsBtn As Control
Dim oCaption As Control

Dim oTxtLen As Integer

oTxtLen1 = TextBox1.Width
oTxtBrth1 = TextBox1.Height
oTxtPos1 = TextBox1.Left

oButLen = CommandButton1.Width
oButBrth = CommandButton1.Height

oTxtLen2 = TextBox2.Width
oTxtBrth2 = TextBox2.Height

If i = Empty Then
    i = 1
End If

    Set oTxtBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    Set oBrwsBtn = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    Set oCaption = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")

    With oTxtBox
        .Left = oTxtPos1
        .Top = oTxtBrth1 + 18 + (oTxtBrth + 18) * (i - 1)
        .Width = oTxtLen1
        .Height = oTxtBrth1
    End With

    With oBrwsBtn
        .Left = oTxtPos1 + oTxtLen1 + 18
        .Top = oTxtBrth1 + 18 + (oTxtBrth + 18) * (i - 1)
        .Width = oButLen
        .Height = oButBrth
    End With


    With oCaption
        .Left = oTxtPos1 + oTxtLen1 + 18 + oButLen + 18
        .Top = oTxtBrth1 + 18 + (oTxtBrth + 18) * (i - 1)
        .Width = oTxtLen2
        .Height = oTxtBrth2
    End With

    i = i + 1
```

**Q1** Now How to Edit the caption of the browse Button which I create dynamically **No method** `.Caption` with `oBrWsBtn`

**And Q2**: How to get the value when the focus is changed
For example When I click on 'TextBox1' Object. A variable should assign itself with the name (i. e. var(str) = focus object name)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Why don't you try defining the control type more specifically and see if that permits you to use the .`Caption` method. Don't understand why it's not working now, but maybe the `Control` object type doesn't have the `.Caption` method because not all controls have captions.

Try:

```
'at the top of the sub:
Dim oBrwsBtn as CommandButton

'then later
Set oBrwsBtn = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
```

Another option to consider would be to create these buttons and just have them be invisible until needed. But that assumes you don't actually have a good reason to create them dynamically, which you may have.

Q2: Use a control_AfterUpdate sub:

```
'Dim this wherever appropriate for scope. Could be in the afterupdate sub if that works.
dim TextBox1_Value as string 

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
     TextBox1_Value = TextBox1.value
End Sub
```